# Excel : VBA , Passing Variable from one sub to another

Tags: excel, vba

I pasted this without header

TT/21-22/079    PROD/22-23/02186    RSM4L50X50X6    16153   6000
TT/21-22/079    PROD/23-24/04956    RSM4L50X50X6    12950
TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/01818    RSM4L50X50X6    9003
TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/01821    RSM4L50X50X6    8349
TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/01548    RSM4L50X50X6    5418
TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/00794    RSM4L50X50X6    4945
TT/21-22/079    PROD/23-24/05081    RSM4L50X50X6    4650

E1.value = 6000 'for table refrence
Trying to compare two columns and running another sub to select some data.
First part of code will find nearest value E1.value i.e row number 5 and put it in some variable as row counter

The next part will take the row counter i.e number 5 and select all rows below until E1.value is finished, this case only one row will be selected.

TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/01548    RSM4L50X50X6    5418

I am trying to create or pass row counter from one sub to another to make my code look neat or I am not doing it right because, the code is stopping only at first sub.

```
Option Explicit
Dim j As Integer


Sub Compare_First()

Dim resultCell As Range, Dim checkCell As Double, Dim bestDiff As Double
checkCell = Range("E1").Value
bestDiff = checkCell

For j = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If Range("D" & j).Value <= checkCell Then
        If (checkCell - Range("D" & j).Value) < bestDiff Then
            bestDiff = checkCell - Range("D" & j)
            Set resultCell = Range("D" & j)
        End If
    End If
Next j
MsgBox "Best match is in " & resultCell.Address
                
Set resultCell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub test()

    Dim TempReq As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lrD As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    maxValue As Long
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("RReq")
    lrD = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
    maxValue = sht.Range("E1").Value
    For i = j To lrD
        TempReq = TempReq + sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If TempReq > maxValue Then 'went over the limit
            Set Rng = sht.Range("A1:D" & i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Rng Is Nothing Then 'didn't reach it
        Set Rng = sht.Range("A1:D" & i - 1)
        MsgBox "Maximum never reached"
    Else
        MsgBox "Maximum reached on row " & i - 1
    End If
    Rng.Select 'try not to use Select :)
End Sub
```

Comment: `j = resultCell.row` after `MsgBox "Best match is in " ...`

Comment: If you want to pass the j to test(), you'll need to adjust something, before End Sub in Compare_First : `test(resultCell.Row)` and the Sub test() becomes `Sub test(rPassed As Integer)` (safer to use Long instead of Integer with rows for when you have larger data sets) and then use rPassed, or stick with "j", whichever you prefer. If you don't want to pass it but just call test, then before End Sub you need `test` (the word `Call` isn't needed to run a sub from another sub) together with what CDP said.

Comment: Welp, I replied to hastily, use CDP's code regardless and then `test(j)` if you want to pass the variable (then the j variable doesn't need to be a public variable).

Comment: @Notus_Panda, thanks for the reply. I am trying to make it work by creating a main program and calling both one by one, Sub Main() call compare_first call test end sub and using code to get value of j=resultcell.row but still the code is not executing.

Call SO
Call test


End Sub

Comment: By *nearest value* do you mean in either positive or negative direction. ie the `ABS()` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use:

```
Option Explicit

Dim j As Long

Sub Main()
    Compare_First
    test
End Sub

Sub Compare_First()

    Dim resultCell As Range, Dim checkCell As Double, Dim bestDiff As Double
    checkCell = Range("E1").Value
    bestDiff = checkCell

    For j = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        If Range("D" & j).Value <= checkCell Then
            If (checkCell - Range("D" & j).Value) < bestDiff Then
                bestDiff = checkCell - Range("D" & j)
                Set resultCell = Range("D" & j)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    j = resultCell.Row
    MsgBox "Best match is in " & resultCell.Address
                
    Set resultCell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub test()

    Dim TempReq As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lrD As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxValue As Long
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("RReq")
    lrD = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
    maxValue = sht.Range("E1").Value
    For i = j To lrD
        TempReq = TempReq + sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If TempReq > maxValue Then 'went over the limit
            Set Rng = sht.Range("A" & j & ":D" & i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Rng Is Nothing Then 'didn't reach it
        Set Rng = sht.Range("A" & j & ":D" & i - 1)
        MsgBox "Maximum never reached"
    Else
        MsgBox "Maximum reached on row " & i - 1
    End If
    Rng.Select 'try not to use Select :)
End Sub
```

I adjusted the ranges to incorporate the j-value as the start and there was a Dim missing for maxValue.
Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome :)